# Собственная аннотация для контроллера

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, аннотации

Всем привет! Нужно создать аннотацию, которая будет использоваться в контроллере рядом с параметром id сущности. Примерно так:

```
public Responce<...Dto> getEntity(@CheckExist(entityClass = {ClassName}.class) @PathVariable id) {
}
```

Аннотация должна проверять существует ли сущность с указанным id или нет)
Класс аннотации:

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface CheckExist {
    Class entityClass();
}
```

Процессор:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.vet24.web.controllers.annotations.CheckExist")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_11)
public class CheckExistProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (TypeElement annotation : annotations) {
            Set<? extends Element> annotatedElements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation);
            for (Element annotatedElement : annotatedElements) {
            
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Что нужно указать в форе, чтобы аннотация заработала как нужно?) Не понимаю как с помощью рефлексии вытащить параметр метода

Comment: Не понятно. Объясните, что значит "указать Reflections или хотя бы Object".

Comment: @Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA переоформил вопрос)

Comment: Похоже, что Вашу задачу можно решить через стандартный механизм валидации спринга. Почитайте про интерфейс Validator.

Comment: @zolt так Валидатор же не даст возможность использовать рефлексию, чтобы получить универсальное решение. А костылить 100 валидаторов на 100 контроллеров, думаю, не самая лучшая идея. Либо я чего-то не понимаю)